# Do moved questions count for tumbleweed badge?

Tags: support, tumbleweed-badge, migration

Are Tumbleweed badges awarded to questions that are moved between sites?

I asked a question on Stackoverflow, that was meant for Serverfault. A moderator moved it after a day. Now after a big week, 14 views and no comments or answers I would expect a badge on serverfault.

Didn't I get it because of the transfer?

Comment: What question are you talking about?

Comment: @Kop http://serverfault.com/questions/183552/shrinking-amazon-ebs-volume-size

Comment: There are two votes there, so you shouldn't be able to get the badge: http://serverfault.com/posts/183552/timeline

Comment: @Yi Aah, thanks! I read over that part of the tumbleweed definition!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asked a question with **no votes**, no answers, no comments, and low views for a week